# How can I un-hide the main form when a sub-form closes?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm trying to make a VB.net program and I have added this code to the main form:

```
Me.Hide()
```

When Form2 opens, the main form hides itself, but if I close Form2 the main Form won't reappear, though I can see it in the Task Manager.

What should I add to make the main form appear again if Form2 closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Form2's `FormClosing` event to show your main form.

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Form2.FormClosing
    Form1.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, when i try to use it i get this error http://gyazo.com/de9e1f131eb8846b67a78fc8d13664de

Comment: Delete the underlined parenthesis at the end of the line. It should only read `Me.FormClosing`.